# How to compare a drawable inside an imageView with another drawable?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I have a drawable inside an imageView and I need to know which drawable is to modify it.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dice_image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/empty_dice"
    tools:src="@drawable/dice_1"/>
```

I already tried with constant state but it's deprecated and works sometimes

Comment: It’s not practical to compare drawables repeatedly. If they are a bitmap you would have to check every pixel of both images. If you don’t know which image is currently in the view, you would have to load other images just to compare them. Better to just keep track of what image is currently loaded using an enum in a separate property.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I put a tag inside each imageview to be able to track what image was inside. Every time I changed the image I updated the tag number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).